# Recarregar script sempre que acontecer o evento

Tags: java, jquery, html5

Olá. estava procurando e não achei nada relacionado por aqui, então estou vindo perguntar.
Eu estou trabalhando com o um plugin 'http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/', e quero dar algumas funções para ele ficar melhor.

Eu já fiz um campo de upload de imagem, mas esse não da submit, estou usando o FileReader para carregar a imagem.
O que está acontecendo, o script desse plugin é executado de modo 'static' ou seja, ele entra em ação assim que o script é carregado, desta forma, não consigo fazer o redimensionamento da foto que foi renderizada.

Queria saber se há como a cada evento de 'change' no input ele recarregar o script, assim ele consegue pegar as informações da imagem.

Answer (score 0):

Bruno, vc pode criar uma função para realizar a busca do plugin de forma assíncrona. Desta forma, assim que o campo mudar, chama a função de carregamento.

```
function loadScript(scriptName, callback) {
    if (!jsArray[scriptName]) {
        jsArray[scriptName] = true;

        // Adiciona o script na head do documento
        var body    = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
            script  = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src  = scriptName;

        // então vincula o evento ao callback passado
        script.onload = callback;

        // dispara o carregamento
        body.appendChild(script);

        // Limpa a referência do DOM
        //body = null;
        //script = null;

    } else if (callback) {

        // Executa o Callback
        callback();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi na resposta anterior, o script eh carregado apenas uma vez, entao aqui segue uma melhoria

```
function loadScript(scriptName) {
        // Adiciona o script na head do documento
        var body    = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
            script  = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src  = scriptName;

        // dispara o carregamento
        body.appendChild(script);

        // Limpa a referência do DOM
        //body = null;
        //script = null;

}
```